# Eloquent belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel-4

in a

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Parent', 'parent_id');
}
```

relationship `$child->parent` results in `NULL` whereas testing `$child->parent()->first()` works as intended.

Is that how it's supposed to be or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the local key to work.
Try this: return `$this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

Comment: Why do I need to use `hasMany`

Comment: do you want an inverse of a relation right?  Set the example to see it more clearly, anyway look at the manual: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Could you point me to why according to manual my example wouldn't work? -- the code is perfectly fine. My guess is that DataTable plugin is messing stuff up

Comment: Your example is fine, I think the problem is in the model or table , please put the models and tables to help you, I would like to help